# Are events passed through the OS?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, events, operating-system

First, if events originate from a hardware input how does the OS detect these events? Is this achieved through polling or maybe the BIOS? How then would the BIOS catch these events? Polling? They can't use an API because it's interacting with the hardware, or can they?

Second, does the OS pass these events up the chain, for example, to browsers which pass them to higher level programming languages like javascript?

Third, does all event driven models eventually rely on a polling mechanism to detect the events on the OS/BIOS level? Can we ever have a true "push" system in event driven programming if this is the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the risk over oversimplification, these days most events start out as interrupts. The hardware triggers a CPU interrupt, that dispatches to an interrupt handler.

The interrupt handler then decides what to do with them.

If a process has registered in some way to be notified of the interrupt, two things can happen:

1. The OS can trigger a software interrupt. This interrupts the normal running of the process and invokes a function the process has declared to handle "things." A process can usually have multiple functions handle different interrupts.
2. The OS can create an event that it adds to an event queue. The process reads from the queue to figure out what is happening (the MS-Windoze/X Windows programming model).

In fact, Windoze uses both of these mechanisms. The underlying NT system was designed to use software interrupts (with the presentation manager UI). When Windoze 3 took off, M$ switched to the WIndoze interface which hides the underling software interrupt system

Polling may be used for some types of devices but that is becoming increasingly less common. In the old days you had to repeatedly poll a Joystick to determine its position for one instances. A flight sim would have to repeatedly poll the joystick to determine the direction to go and, to do that, it would have to poll several times.

Thus, the usual sequence is the OS gets interrupts > OS handles the interrupts > OS creates queue entries > application picks entries off the queue.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, I was just wondering how the interrupt handler works? This article [link](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Unix-and-Internet-Fundamentals-HOWTO/devices.html) makes it seem like the interrupt handler is controlled by the OS? If so how does the interrupt handler wait for/receive interrupts?

Comment: No. There OS defines a table of handlers for interrupts, traps, and faults. Divide by zero and an interrupt get handled in the same way. When an interrupt occurs, the OS interrupts what it is doing, switches to kernel mode, then calls the handler assigned to the interrupt.

Oddly, whatever process that is executing at the time handles the interrupt. Bill's application can handle the interrupt for Fred's disk read.

Comment: So the CPU calls the interrupt handler so it doesn't have to poll?

Comment: Yes. Or rather the hardware triggers the CPU to call the interrupt handler.